# Can I create in a view an atribute for each tuple, enumerating it?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Imagine I create a view, using the atributes B, C and D. Can I, in the view, create a new atribute (lets call it A) enumerating each tuple of the view? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this

```
CREATE VIEW vw_table1
AS
SELECT rownum a , b, c, d
  FROM table1
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/450c9/1)**